# How do I show sets have the same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> How do I show that $\left[a,b \right]$ and $\left(a,b \right)$ have the same cardinality where $a<b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\ f:[a,b]\rightarrow\ (a,b)$ with

$f(x)$=$\ \begin{cases} 
      \frac{(a+b)}{2} &if\  x= a \\
      a+\frac{b-a}{n+2} &if\  x=a+\frac{b-a}{n},n\in\mathbb N \\
      x &if\  x≠a,a+\frac{b-a}{n},n\in\mathbb N 
   \end{cases}
\
$

$f$ is one-to-one and onto.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by constructing a bijection between the two sets $A,B$. If you have a bijection between two sets, then it is implied that every element of $A$ corresponds to exactly one element of $B$. So the sets must have the same cardinality.